# Format Date VARIABLE to short date VBA

Tags: vba, date, time

I have a user inputted via a userform.textbox.value.  General date that I want to switch to a short date. (Or try to get the time to drop so it reads 00:00). I tried the code

`sDate=format(date,(d))`

but that returns the current date rather than the variable date without the time. I mainly just want to drop the time so if there is an easier way to do that I would be accepting of the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, see: [Format function](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/format_date.php).

**Usage:**

```
'UserForm has a TextBox named TxtDate
Dim myDate As Date, sDate As String

myDate  = Me.TxtDate 'DateSerial(2014,12,11)

sDate = Format(myDate, "Short Date")
'or
sDate = Format(myDate, "yyyy/MM/dd")
```

Comment: That's essentially the same thing if I am not mistaken. I was using that page as a reference when I began. However, I plugged your code into my code and it returned the current date rather than the date that I have supplied.

Comment: I guess I'm not very clear with what I am trying to say. sDate comes from a userform.textbox.value that the user inputs. So that option doesn't quite work either. My mistake on not being clear

Comment: Thanks! Very new to coding so everything is hard for me haha